# Intellij Idea Kotlin, Internal error: failed to generate main function

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

i just started learning Kotlin and downloaded IntelliJ idea and made this very simple file:

```
fun  main()
{
    println("hello Kotlin !");
}
```

and when i try to run it, it gives me an error:

> Kotlin: [Internal Error]
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM)
> Internal error: Failed to generate function main.

I have tried reinstalling and google around for a bit but didn't find a lot of people with the same problem. Here is the screenshot of the file structure if that might be the issue:
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Z9b.png)

any help would be appreaciated, thanks !

Comment: Have you looked here? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/jvm-get-started.html Also, what build system are you using. I have some experience using it with Maven, so can help if that is what you are using.

Comment: Try to create a default project through "File | New project" in IDEA with all default values. Does the error still occur? Can you post the full stack trace including all "Caused by" clauses?

Comment: Just created a new project, and did the same, it functions properly now. That was super weird!